# Best Practices for setting up multi-server LAMP environment

Tags: linux, web-server, lamp

I'm **looking for resources** that will help me design an optimum multi-user multi-server LAMP environment.

We currently have 7 servers (2 load-balanced webservers, 2 redundant clustered web-content servers, 2 redundant clustered MySQL servers, 1 VirtualMin Developer server), but am having difficulty **determining if what I have done is common/optimum/good practice**, etc.

Can anyone point me to any good/great resources for designing (and running) multi-server LAMP environments?

Note:
*I asked this question on StackOverflow some time ago, but didn't get any great results.  Perhaps I should have waited until the end of the Beta (for more of a non-SO audience)*

Comment: you can't spell best practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For configuration management take a look at tools like [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet) and [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home). There are others you might want to check as well, like [capistrano](http://www.capify.org). Also, you want to keep an eye on those servers when they enter production mode. For monitoring, you might want to check [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org). And there are lots of others, some of them based on [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/rrdworld/index.en.html).

Comment: Thanks, we use nagios very extensively, and are very happy  with that.  As for puppet and capistrano, our servers are all in clusters, and so there is no manual duplication of data.  Haven't heard off "chef" though, I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Any environment of sufficient complexity (that is, any at all, really) should be under configuration management, whether it be Chef or Puppet. My preference is Chef and there's a set of cookbooks (configuration modules) that will help in setting up end-to-end the entirety of a [LAMP stack](http://github.com/opscode/cookbooks) (or my preference, [LAMRails](http://github.com/opscode/rails_infra_repo/tree/master)). There's also EC2 AMIs available for setting up an [entire Rails infrastructure on Amazon EC2](http://blog.opscode.com/2009/05/deploying-rails-infrastructures-with-chef.html), and this can be a good baseline to look at for considerations about setting up your own environment.